# First c++ class and not sure on some things. specifically "const std::string& prompt

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters

This is my first assignment and I am a little confused.  It is supposed to ask favorite color, integer, then float and then print the color and float (integer) amount of times.  I have created a few files and I believe properly #included them and such but something is going wrong.  I knew it wasnt going to work I was just trying to get it to do something when I "make"ed it but I am not sure how to move forward.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "image_menu.h"
#include <string>

std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    std::string color;
    os << "What's your favorite color? ";
    is >> color;
    return color;
}

int getInteger(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    int num;
    os << "What's your favorite number? ";
    is >> num;
    return num;
}

double getDouble(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    double dec;
    os << "What's your favorite float? ";
    is >> dec;
    return dec;
}

int assignment1(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os){
    getString(is, os);
    getInteger(is, os);
    getDouble(is, os);
    return num;
```

my main

```
#include "image_menu.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    assignment1(std::cin, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef _IMAGE_MENU_H_
#define _IMAGE_MENU_H_
#include <iostream>
std::string getString( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt );
int getInteger( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt );
double getDouble( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt );
int assignment1( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os );
#endif // _IMAGE_MENU_H_
```

and my Makefile

```
all: assignment

assignment: ppm_menu.o image_menu.o
    g++ -std=c++11 -o assignment ppm_menu.o image_menu.o

ppm_menu.o: ppm_menu.cpp image_menu.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c ppm_menu.cpp

image_menu.o: image_menu.cpp image_menu.h
    g++ -std=c++11 -c image_menu.cpp
```

I know it is asking a lot to have you guys look over it.  I am not asking for you to do my homework for me just to help me understand the `const std::string& prompt` stuff.  I have a basic enough understanding I think to complete the assignment just not sure what to do with that parameter.  (We were given the function name and params by the teacher other than that we are on our own)

Thank you so so much for any help!

Instructions for the file I'm having troubles with

```
std::string getString( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt ); This function must display the prompt to the output stream, read a string response from the input stream and return the string.
int getInteger( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt ); This function must display the prompt to the output stream, read an integer response from the input stream and return the integer.
double getDouble( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt ); This function must display the prompt to the output stream, read a double precision floating point response from the input stream and return the double.
int assignment1( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os ); This function must get a string from the input stream, using the prompt “What’s your favorite color? “, an integer using the prompt “What’s your favorite integer? “, and a double precision floating point number using the prompt “What’s your favorite number? “. It must then repeatedly send the line described above in the assignment description to the output stream. Returns the integer number given by the user.
```

Comment: Your question is focussed enough, however, what I don't uderstand is where the prompt parameter comes from. My guess is that you shouldn't hard-code "What's your favorite color? " in `getString` as you can use the same function for requesting a name.

Comment: We cannot know what your functions are supposed to do. That should be in your assignment. But it seems most likely to me that you are supposed to use `prompt` as input prompt to the user, instead of writing your own as in `"What's your favorite float? "`.

Comment: @walnut @JVApen so that is actually supposed to be filled in as a param for example where I call `int assignment1`

Comment: So then do os << prompt to use the parameter instead of hard coding it correct?

Comment: @ShaneBowe See answer by Aconcagua which covers what I wanted to write in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

First thing that you might note that your code won't compile:

```
getString(is, os);
```

The function expects three parameters, but you only provide two. At very least, you'd provide some dummy value, e. g. empty string:

```
getString(is, os, "");
```

As there's a non-explicit constructor accepting a `char const*` for `std::string`, a temporary object will be created that will be destroyed again immediately on completion of above expression (i. e. after the function returning).

So far the technical stuff. However, you might be asked for different strings in further tasks. Something like forename, surename, city you live, ... Would you want to write separate functions for all these? Here comes the prompt into play: Provide the actual question you want to ask as prompt. Then `getString` might look like this:

```
std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt)
{
    std::string color; // perhaps rather name it 'value', you won't be asking
                       // for colors all the time...
    os << prompt << ' ';
    is >> color;
    return color;
}
```

And you might call it like:

```
getString(is, os, "What's your favorite color?");
```

Analogously the other functions.

---

<sup>*Side-note (after edit of question): This indeed is what the task actually requires...*</sup>

Comment: I just finished doing this to them haha, thank you so much for typing that all out!  I still am running into "too few parameters" for some reason here is what I have

Comment: @ShaneBowe But number of parameters is correct. On the other hand, what's that about `return num;` in `assignment1`? There's no num defined. Maybe you discovered the old errors from previous compilation and overlooked the one for the latter when compiling again. Try clearing the console and re-compile.

Comment: I am supposed to return the number that getInteger returns, that's the problem I am running into now haha, it says that num is out of scope but wouldn't it be within as I'm calling getInteger inside with it?

Comment: I updates my question with what I'm supposed to have, I am supposed to be able to use the inputs to print out but it says they're out of scope

Comment: @ShaneBowe Well, you'll need to store that number somewhere: `int num = getInteger(...);`. Then you can return it afterwards. Be aware that this `num` is not the same as the one in `getInteger`, the two just happen to have the same name. You cannot access functions' local variables from other functions (you even create separate variables on recursive calls of the same function!).

Comment: Ok i actually figured it out haha, I finished it how its supposed to be I ran it once and now when I try to run it again it just gives me ./ is a directory.  Did I save it wrong maybe?  Sorry for so many questions.  I'm fairly new to all of this stuff. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @ShaneBowe *' `./` is a directory'* – you seem to have forgotton to provide executable name (`./application1` or whatever it is called).

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down what a `const std::string&` is

`const` is an identifier in c++ that is put before a type to show that the type cannot be modified after initialization.

For example the following code will not compile
    const int x = 5;
    x = 10;

However, this will.

```
 int x = 5;
 x = 10
```

`std::string` is a class that represents an array of characters.

`&` is called a reference. A reference has similar semantics to a pointer but don't worry about this for now.

Let's look at your first function.

```
std::string getString( std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt );
```

It takes 3 arguments, an input stream reference which uses the `>>` operator, an output stream reference which uses the `<<` operator, and a std::string.

This probably looks familiar.

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

It prints the string "Hello World!" to stdout. std::cout has the same type as the second variable in all of your functions namely `os`.

The first issues is how you're calling it.

```
getString(is, os);
```

You're passing two but it expects three!

It looks like you should write your prompt in your function call... By that I mean,

```
getString(is, os);
```

becomes

```
getString(is, os, "what is your favorite string");
```

Then in your function definition for `getString` you don't want to hardcode that string. you want to use whatever the caller passes! i.e.

```
std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt)
{
    std::string color;
    os << prompt;
    is >> color;
    return color;
}
```

Bonus points - Since you were confused by the `const std::string&` let's dissect this a little further.

If our function looked like this instead,

std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, std::string& prompt);

and we defined it as

```
std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, std::string& prompt)
{   
    std::string color;
    os << prompt;
    is >> color;
    prompt = "What is your favorite dog?";
    return color;
}
```

What do you think would happen if we called this function twice like,

```
getString(is, os, "What is your favorite color?");
getString(is, os, "What is your favorite color?");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it!  Now a new problem, num at the end there is not being defined in the scope.  Shoudn't it be because I am running the getInteger function inside assignment1? @skam

Comment: I updates my question with what I'm supposed to have, I am supposed to be able to use the inputs to print out but it says they're out of scope

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out thanks to some amazing help!  Thank you guys so much for all of the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "image_menu.h"
#include <string>

std::string getString(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    std::string color;
    os << prompt;
    is >> color;
    return color;
}

int getInteger(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    int num;
    os << prompt;
    is >> num;
    return num;
}

double getDouble(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os, const std::string& prompt) {
    double dec;
    os << prompt;
    is >> dec;
    return dec;
}

int assignment1(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os){
    std::string color = getString(is, os, "What is your favorite color? ");
    int num = getInteger(is, os, "What is your favorite number? ");
    double dec = getDouble(is, os, "What is your favorite double? ");
    for(int a=0; a <= num; a = a +1) {
        os << num << " " << color << " " << dec << "\n";
    }
    return num;
}
```

Here's what my finished code looks like!  May not be pretty but it works!